# What does "if (targetStr.indexOf(value) == -1) " condition mean in the below program, so we get correct output

Tags: java

1. what is the meaning of  "if (targetStr.indexOf(value) == -1) "
2. how for loop works here
3. why we have initialise empty String -  String targetStr = ""

```
public class Duplicate_Sentence_Removal_From_String_2019 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str2 = "hello";
        System.out.println(removeDuplicateChars(str2));
    }

    private static String removeDuplicateChars(String sourceStr) {
        // Store encountered letters in this string.
        char[] chrArray = sourceStr.toCharArray();
        String targetStr = "";

        // Loop over each character.
        for (char value : chrArray) {
            // See if character is in the target
            if (targetStr.indexOf(value) == -1) {
                targetStr += value; // Use StringBuilder as shown below
            }
        }
        return targetStr;
    }

}
```

Expected out put is "helo"

Comment: I think that all the code comments answer to your questions

Comment: Read the [String::indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) method and you'll see that *the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character does not occur.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. -1 is returned when you don't find the value.
2. The loop says for each character (here called value) inside chArray try to locate another identical character in targetStr, if you don't find another add the character to targetStr. So basically if you enter hello it would go like this:

value = h -> try to find another h -> gets -1 (so no other h) -> add h to the return

value = e -> try to find another e -> gets -1 (so no other e) -> add e to the return

value = l -> try to find another l -> gets -1 (so no other l) -> add l to the return

value = l -> try to find another l -> gets 2 (position of l) -> don't add l

value = o -> try to find another o -> gets -1 (so no other o) -> add o to the return

3. You can't do targetStr.indexOf() or targetStr += value if targetStr is not initialized and can't return a non-initialized variable